# Error UNKNOWN with node.js swig consolidate

Tags: node.js, express, swig-template

I'm getting this error in the all of the templates that I include using this:

```
{% include '../public/templates/header.html' %}
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

```
Error: UNKNOWN, unknown error '//../public/templates/header.html'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
at getSingle (C:\project\node_modules\swig\lib\swig.js:152:19)
at get (C:\project\node_modules\swig\lib\swig.js:159:7)
at Object.exports.compileFile (C:\project\node_modules\swig\lib\swig.js:177:7)
at eval (eval at createRenderFunc (C:\project\node_modules\swig\lib\swig.js:44:10), :13:22)
at Object.eval (eval at createRenderFunc (C:\project\node_modules\swig\lib\swig.js:44:10), :15:3)
at Object.template.render (C:\project\node_modules\swig\lib\swig.js:111:21)
at C:\project\node_modules\swig\lib\swig.js:189:17
at Function.exports.swig.render (C:\project\node_modules\consolidate\lib\consolidate.js:245:14)
```

Comment: Could it be that it's not finding the file? What is swig.js doing at line 177?

Comment: It worked yesterday. And I haven't done any changes to the path or to the location of the file. Tried reinstalling swig and consolidate too, with no luck.

Comment: What is it doing at line 177? Also, the first two `//` in the template path are strange...

Comment: Yeah, seems like swig ads the //

Comment: What version of swig are you using (the lines in the stack trace don't match up with the most recent version, 1.2.2)? Where is the template located that has the line of code you provided?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Swig @v0.14.0, which is severely outdated. The entire engine was rewritten for v1.0.0, which brought about the ability to use relative paths. This feature previously didn't exist, so you always had to use absolute paths relative to your `root`.

If you continue using v0.14.0, assuming your `root == './public/templates'` or similar:

```
{% include '/header.html' %}
```

However, I'd highly recommend updating to the newest version, Swig @~1.2 for compatibility and support purposes.